# Spark Job hanging

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am running a spark job on yarn cluster through the `spark-submit` command. The job starts but hangs at action steps. Below is the command I am using for this:

```
spark-submit \
--class com.spark.Inbound \
--name spark-learning \
--deploy-mode cluster \
--queue default \
--conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-
Dlog4j.configuration=file:/home_dir/sam/log4j.properties \
--conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-
Dlog4j.configuration=file:/home_dir/sam/log4j.properties \
--conf spark.logConf=true \
sparkscala_2.11-1.0.jar dev.

   val inputFileData = sparkContext.textFile(sourceConfig.employeeInLocation + "/" + sourceConfig.employeeInFileName)
inputFileData.
.flatMap(data => data.split("\n"))
.foreach(println(_))
```

The same job, when running without the `log4j` properties, finishes successfully.

```
spark-submit \
--class com.spark.Inbound \
--name spark-learning \
--deploy-mode cluster \
--queue default \
sparkscala_2.11-1.0.jar dev.
```

Am I missing any parameters?

Comment: I have figured out the problem myself.

Comment: What did you do to solve this?